# Slowly move a circle in PIXIJS

Tags: html5-canvas, pixi.js

I have a circle with PIXI and I need that when the touch is fulfilled another object said circle returns to its original position, but it happens that I do not know any function or method for the movement to be appreciable, all I have achieved is that it disappear and appear in its initial position. How did the transition happen?

Comment: Please, if you made some attemps of source code, can you share writing it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the movement into rendering loop

I use PIXI.tickerTicker() for loop

```
let ticker  =  new PIXI.ticker.Ticker();
```

the rendering loop in your situation should be

```
function loop(){

    renderer.render(stageContainer);
    yourCircle.position.x += moveSpeed; //your question
    if(resetCirclePosition)
        yourCircle.position.x = defaultPos;

}
```

and then to start ticker use

```
ticker.add(loop);
ticker.start();
```

Look at ticker documentation http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.ticker.Ticker.html